# Extract variable value with variable name (Regex)

Tags: python, regex, beautifulsoup

I have a  tag with multiple variable definitions such as:

```
<script>
    var name1="value1";var name2="value2";var name3="value3";
</script>
```

I extract it with BeautifulSoup and it is returned as a string:

```
'var name1="value1";var name2="value2";var name3="value3";'
```

How can I get the variable value if I know the variable name?

Comment: Is it **really** as contained as that? You don't have to allow for comments, other code, other line breaks, spaces around `=`, `'` instead of `"`, template literals, numbers, functions returning the value, ...

Comment: My point is: This is possible with a single regular expression for the example quoted, but not for JavaScript code in general. For that you need a JavaScript parser.

Comment: Yes, I want extract the variable value since it is in a string returned from BeautifulSoup

Comment: For that matter: The example is invalid JavaScript. Is that intentional? (You can't have `var` after the comma in a `var` statement.)

Comment: I correct the example. Sorry for the mistake

Comment: Why not get the values first in JS, instead of outside?

Comment: So this is not a javascript question but instead this should be marked as a python question. You don't want to use javascript to extact the files, please fix your tag.

Comment: *"Yes, I want extract the variable value since it is in a string returned from BeautifulSoup"* does not answer my question in the first comment above.

Comment: There are not spaces. I put the ' ant beggining and end for undestand of it is a string

Comment: So, I have this string: `var name1="value1";var name2="value2";var name3="value3";`  I want to get `value1` if I have `name1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With regex:

```
parameter = # Requested parameter value
parsed_code = # JS snippet

regex_string = 'var {parameter}="(.*?)"'.format(parameter=parameter)
re.findall(regex_string, parsed_code)
```

Without regex, as this isn't a good use case for it:

```
parameter = # Requested parameter value
parsed_code = # JS snippet

identifying_string = '{parameter}="'.format(parameter=parameter)
value = parsed_code.split(identifying_string)[1].split('"')[0]
```

Both are fairly unsafe and you should consider a different way of doing what you're doing.